# Second call to re.eval("source()) fails with JRI

Tags: java, r, jri

I have installed JRI to run with NetBeans 7.4 using 32-bit R 3.0.2 and Java jdk1.7.0_45, on Windows 7.

I am using the following Java function.

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RList;

void testJRI(){

    // Start JRI engine. 
    String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
    Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);

    if (!re.waitForR()) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load R");
        return null;
    }

    REXP load=re.eval("source('C:\\\\searchPath\\\\nonparametricAnova.r')");
    re.end();

    return;
}
```

The first time the function is called, everything works fine.  But the second time, the variable, load, is null - indicating failure.

I replaced the nonparametricAnova.r R function with the following simple script

```
simple<-function(){
  a=1
  a
}
```

which I named simple.r and called with

```
    REXP load=re.eval("source('C:\\\\searchPath\\\\simple.r')");
```

Now, the second time through, it hangs on

```
Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);
```

I have noticed that

```
load=re.eval("refClusterMeasurements<-read.csv(\"C:/SearchPath/fileName.csv\", header=TRUE)");
```

also fails the second time through, even if "name.csv" is a minimally sized file.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the issue but note that detaching a script doesn't make any sense in R.

Comment: Have you tried sourcing a different (perhaps extremely simple) script in place of nonparametricAnova to see if you have the same issue?

Comment: @Dason.  I tried that and now it hangs on Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);  I have edited my question to reflect that.  Thanks,

Comment: Can you add the imports?

Comment: @Yehoshaphat.  I had edited my question to add the imports.  Thanks,

Comment: Your quotes on your latest edits in the read.csv part are messed up.  Is that what you had in your code?

Comment: can you add a sample data set using `dput(data)` , ill run it in my machine.

Comment: @Yehoshaphat.  If I run the script more than once, it doesn't work on any data.  I tried Rsession.  It has the same basic usage as JRI but does not have this problem.  Thanks,

Comment: could you post the answers (with the right `csv` url), so other users could enjoy is?

Comment: @Yehoshaphat.  I cannot post the data.  It is priority.  I am now using Rsession instead and it works fine.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This version works:

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

/**
 *
 * @author yschellekens
 */
public class StackOverflow {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {




 // Start JRI engine. 
    String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
    Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);

      re.eval("source('C:/Users/yschellekens.INTRANET/Desktop/java projects/simple.R')");
       REXP value =re.eval("as.integer(a<-simple())");
   int a  = value.asInt();
        System.out.println(a);


    }
}
```

using the following R file:

```
simple<-function(){
  a=1
  return(a)
}
```

Java output:

```
run:
1
```

Notice several differences:

1. Don't use `REXP load=` before the `re.eval("source...`
2. Save your r file with `.R`
3. Change your dashes to : `/`

This code work's fine many times, please let me know if that solved the issue.

Comment: It was still hanging after using the above code. Then I added re.end(); just before return and it solved the hanging issue.

Comment: when I am using it as a web service, the first call made returns response but for the second time onwards it got hanged eating memory and CPU.

Comment: I got the solution at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994141/calling-r-script-function-from-java-using-rjava/40104285#40104285)